# Different definitions of sequential homotopy colimits

Tags: model-categories, triangulated-categories

There are two notions of homotopy limits, one for triangulated categories and one for model categories and I wonder whether these two coincide. More concretely, let $\mathcal{T}$ be a triangulated category having countable direct sums and $X_0 \to X_1 \to \cdots $ a sequence of morphisms in $\mathcal{T}$, we define the homotopy colimit of this sequence to be

$$\operatorname{HoLim}(X_i) = \operatorname{Cone}\left(\bigoplus_{i=1}^{\infty} X_i \overset{\operatorname{id} - \operatorname{shift}}{\longrightarrow} \bigoplus_{i=1}^{\infty}X_i \right).$$
Now if $\mathfrak{M}$ is a model category and $\mathbb{N}$ to be the poset $\left \{0 < 1 < 2< \cdots \right \}$, we have a colimit functor $\operatorname{colim} \colon \mathfrak{M}^{\mathbb{N}} \to \mathfrak{M}$ and we define the homotopy colimit as its left derived functor
$$\operatorname{HoLim} = \mathbf{L}\operatorname{colim} \colon \mathbf{Ho}(\mathfrak{M}^{\mathbb{N}}) \longrightarrow \mathbf{Ho}(\mathfrak{M}).$$
My question is, if $\mathcal{T} = \mathbf{Ho}(\mathfrak{M})$ with $\mathfrak{M}$ a stable model category, do these two notions coincide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  First observe that in the triangulated category of a stable model category, the mapping cone of the difference of two morphisms is their homotopy coequalizer and the direct sum of a family of objects is their homotopy coproduct.

Thus, the diagram in the first displayed formula is the homotopy coequalizer of two homotopy coproducts.  The resulting double homotopy colimit can be rewritten as a homotopy colimit over a single indexing category $I$, given by the Grothendieck construction applied to the indexing categories.

In our case, the category $I$ is a poset that has pairs $(i,j)$, $i≥0$, $j∈\{0,1\}$ as objects and $(i,j)<(k,l)$ if $j=0$, $l=1$, and $i≤k≤i+1$.

The projection $\def\N{{\bf N}} I→\N$ induces a functor, which can be easily checked to be ∞-final by computing the comma categories and observing they are weakly contractible.  Thus, the homotopy colimit over $I$ can be computed as the homotopy colimit over $\N$, which completes the proof.

Comment: What do you mean by $\infty$-final and weakly contractible?

Comment: @AlexeyDo: ∞-final means restricting along it does not change homotopy colimits: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/final+(infinity,1)-functor.  Weakly contractible means the map to the terminal object is a weak equivalence: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/contractible+space or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weakly_contractible.

Comment: Your links are $\infty$-stuff, how can they be translated to model categories?

Comment: @AlexeyDo: I am not sure if I understand what you mean by “∞-stuff”. The article on final (∞,1)-functors talks about (∞,1)-functors and (∞,1)-categories, and model categories are one out of many models (of fully equal status) for (∞,1)-categories.  Quasicategories are another one.  There is no need for a “translation”.  An exposition directly in the framework of model categories can be found in Section 19.6 of Hirschhorn's book “Model categories and their localizations”.